# PHPUnit not correctly installed. Can not execute my PHPUnitTest classes

Tags: unix, phpunit, redhat

I am not able to run PHPUnit test after installing PHPUnit using PEAR. This is the following error:

```
[rpteira@f-dev-rpteira tests]$ phpunit
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Zend_Loader::Zend_Loader::registerAutoload is deprecated as of 1.8.0 and will be removed with 2.0.0; use Zend_Loader_Autoloader instead in /usr/share/php/Zend/Loader.php on line 266
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php on line 23

Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php on line 23
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php' (include_path='/home/rpteira/workspace/ums/api/trunk/library:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/php/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php on line 23

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php' (include_path='/home/rpteira/workspace/ums/api/trunk/library:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/php/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php on line 23
[rpteira@f-dev-rpteira tests]$
```

After installing I can see this:

```
[rpteira@f-dev-rpteira tests]$ sudo find / -name PHPUnit
/tmp/ZendFramework-1.11.0/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit
/tmp/ZendFramework-1.11.0/tests/Zend/Test/PHPUnit
/usr/share/php/Zend/Test/PHPUnit
/usr/share/php/Zend-2.0/Test/PHPUnit
/usr/share/pear/doc/PHPUnit
/usr/share/pear/PHPUnit
```

I tried re-installing the package but the same error occurs.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing PHP unit via PEAR is no longer supported. See [phpunit.de](http://phpunit.de/).

You'll probably find it easier to install and maintain if you use [composer](http://getcomposer.org). Detailed instructions on how to install can be found in the [PHPUnit Documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/installation.html).